# How to ng-repeat array inside of td so that td contains all array values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a number of arrays that I need to `ng-repeat` inside of a single `td`. For example, `{"Locations":["San Francisco, CA","Los Angeles, CA"]}`, where the `td` needs to look like

```
<td>San Francisco, CA,Los Angeles, CA</td>
```

or `{"Locations":["Boston","Los Angeles","London","New York","Hongkong","Washington","Seattle","Atlanta","San Francisco","Sydney","Austin"]}`, where the `td` needs to look like

```
<td>Boston,Los Angeles,London,New York, Hongkong, Washington, Seattle, Atlanta, San Francisco, Sydney, Austin</td>
```

I have tried a number of different things, but they all seem to repeat the `td`...here are a few things I tried:

```
td(ng-repeat-start="location in currentSchools.Locations") {{location}}
```

and

```
tr(ng-repeat="location in currentSchools.Locations")
  td
    | {{location}}
```

Comment: I think you should be looking at a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) that joins your array the way you want it, into a single string

Comment: Inside the controller, iterate through the array and concatenate to a single String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a `<span>` tag inside `<td>` element and use ng-repeat on span  element

Comment: How do you use a span inside of a td?

Comment: like this <td> <span></span </td>

Comment: and apply ng-repeat to it

Answer (score 1):

A ng-repeat will repeat the html element that it is declared on for each element in the collection.

It seems you are looking to do more of a string join inside of your  element

so instead you should have a method in your controller like such:

```
$scope.schoolLocationsList = function() {
  return $scope.Locations.join();
}
```

and then in your html you should do

```
<td>{{ schoolLocationsList() }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop inside the `td` using another element like `span`. For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="location in currentSchools.Locations">{{location}}, </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However this will give you a trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array methods inside a template:

```
<td>{{ currentSchools.Locations.join(', ') }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing
`<table><td ng-repeat="location in locations">{{location}}</td></table>`

You'll just have to format it to include commas or any spacing, but hopefully lists your elements out the way you want it to.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/addykim/pen/JdBYpr) a pen as an example.